# What desktop GUI framework to use for development of a Gnome Photo Album app using pygobject

Tags: python

I am planning to develop a Gnome photo album app in GTK3 using Python. It typically has multiple "pages" per "album" with multiple photos per page. These photo's can be arranges on the page, partly overlapping each other, rotated, resized, etc. Each photo can have a choice of borders. Each page can have a choice of background. It needs to be able to be printed as an album or exported as an web based album. You get the idea..

Now, I am completely overwhelmed with the choices of libraries/frameworks that exist: Cairo and it's choice of canvases: https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/ProjectRidley/CanvasOverview/Canvases, GDK, GSK, GTK itself, clutter, and I probably forgot some.

Starting fresh, with no technical debt involved, what is the best suited framework for this type of app in terms of features, stability and future?

Btw, if needed, I would consider switching from Python to Vala.

Comment: What OSes do you need the app to run on?

Comment: Only Linux (Gnome)

Comment: Please add this to your question, thanks! :-)